# Using Go to send messages between VMs?

Tags: go, distributed

I am brand new to Go and new to distributed systems programming in general. My team is doing some messing around with the language and I was wondering what a simple way to send messages between different VMs was using Go?

For example, an example where 2 or more VMs were running some sort of procedure or service, and one of the VMs could send some sort of message to the other VM and have the other VM do something with the data and send back a message of its own.

Any example of 2 VMs communicating with each other using Go would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the [net/rpc](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/) package examples?

Comment: A popular approach for client-server communication is via the REST model. Go does this very well. It wouldn't be as fast as bespoke RPC, but it might possibly suit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

The net rpc package has a nice example [here](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/).

all put together in playground [here](http://play.golang.org/p/YpN1SBQqk7)